# new MacBook, Icloud can't login, got error "the iCloud terms of conditions have changed."

Tags: macos

I got myself a new mac from an old one, but it keeps asking “how to agree to iCloud terms and conditions”, how do I accept these?

Comment: What does "a new mac from an old one" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: macbook air2013 13 inch, to macbook 14 pro 2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Mail app, then from the top menu select `Mail > Accounts`, it'll open the `Internet Accounts` window like in the image attached, as you click on each of the iCloud email accounts it will ask уоu to agree on new terms & conditions, once уоu agree on them all the problem should be resolved.[image]